# AWX Failing to install requirements from private repo

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I have an AWX installation with a project. The project is fetched perfectly from the private git repo.

The project has a requirements file which is executed by AWX. The requirements file contains private repositories like this:

```
- src: git+http://gitlab.test.com/ansible/test.git
  version: master
  name: test
```

This however fails with the following error:

test was NOT installed successfully: - command git clone failed in directory.

How can I configure AWX to use the git credentials that are in place already in awx?

Comment: Are the main project and requirement on different git(lab) installations and/or using different credentials ? I just had a look at the gui and I don't see how to manage this case unfortunately. We use ssh with a deploykey declared for all needed requirements repos. All the others have anonymous access. Looks like a limitation I hadn't bumped into yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like AWX works 'smarter' than I thought it would.

In this case, AWX used the same credentials that it used to fetch the project in the first place. I had two options to resolve this:

- Change the links to work via git
- Update the same git credential and also add the username and password of that git user.